# What happened to the rerun button in GitHub checks?

Tags: github, github-check-run

I can't share any screenshots for proprietary reasons, but has the re-run button for GitHub checks been removed? It used to be that you could click "Checks" on a pull request, and there would be a button that you could press to trigger a webhook specifying this run should be done again.

Is this a problem on my end, or has this feature been removed? As far as I can tell, it just disappeared at some point. The documentation for GitHub checks is remarkably sparse and vague, I'm having a hard time figuring out what to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about GitHub Enterprise, it might depends on its version.

But a GitHub check, [from its documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-status-checks#checks) offer rerun for *failed* checks.

So:

- either those checks are not failed
- or there is a permission issue which would make your profile unable to access the rerun feature (check with your GitHub Enterprise admin)

Answer (score 0):

Try to close PR and reopen. It worked for me in restarting all checks again.